# How to call the Function of the Fragment from the Main activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

First let me tell you what I am trying to do. 
I have an activity with navigation drawer and some fragment classes. On activity resume I am calling a MapFragment which I am using to show the user its current location with the blue dot on google map.

This is running successfully .

Now from the navigation drawer I want to show the pins on the map , so for this I am calling the function which is used to download pins from the server and to show them on map. This function is named as GetAllPins , I am doing this in the following manner using Ion library:

```
 public void GetAllPins() {

        progressDialog.show();
 Ion.with(getActivity())
                .load(MyServiceUrl)
                .progressHandler(new ProgressCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(long downloaded, long total) {
                        if (downloaded == total) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setMultipartParameter("name", "Stacy")
                .setMultipartParameter("latitude","18.92239u")
                .setMultipartParameter("longitude", "24.98329")
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                        if (result == null) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error in establishing connection with server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Completed successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
);
}
```

> Note : This is working fine and plotting pins successfully when called inside MyMapFragment's onActivityCreated Method , but giving me a NullpointerException when I try to call it from the MainActivity.

In MainActivity I am calling it in switch case as I am using SwitchCase to navigate to fragments accordingly .

public void navigateToFragment(int pos) {

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    final MyMapFragment myMapFragment = new MyMapFragment();
    switch (pos) {


        case R.id.home:
            if(!isFirstRun) {

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, myMapFragment, "MapFragment").addToBackStack("MapFragment").commit();
            }else{
                isFirstRun=false;
            }
            //
            break;

        case R.id.mark_pin:
            isFirstRun=false;
            if (myMapFragment!=null){
           myMapFragment.GetAllPins();}
                        break;
                    }
```

So I am getting a Null pointerException on ProgressDialog , but if I comment out the following an error occures.

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can not pass null context in to retrieve ion instance
```

Tell me how to call this function from the main activity to show the pins on the map using that MyMapFragment. 
I do not want to make a different fragment of map to show the pins on it. Please help me.

Comment: Add parameter context to method and pass it when you call it with different context

Comment: it is giving me same NullpointerException error

Comment: Can you expand the logcat output and show at what lines does the code break

Comment: Ion.with(context) .... on this line ............

when I did   public void GetAllPins(Context context) {

Comment: Try using `Log.e("Context", "Context: " + context);` when you call the method, see when you are trying to pass in the null context

Comment: should i write this line in my GetAllPins method

Comment: No, just before you call it. Use the same context you are trying to pass in later. For example: if you are trying to pass it from Fragment you should use getActivity, if you are passing it from activity it should probably be this or getApplicationContext()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83306/discussion-between-stacy-queen-and-slorangex).

Answer (score 0):

From the log itself, itz clear that the error iz where the context is called... From fragment, u will get proper context when you call getActivity()... But when u call the same method from MainActivity, the getActivity() will return null... So itz better to add context as a parameter to the function and when calling from fragment, call it by passing getActivity() and from MainActivity call it by passing 'this'...

I didnt Test it... But it should work...

Call the function from MainActivity like this,  **fragment.GetAllPins(MainActivity.this);**

When u call from fragment, it should be like this, **GetAllPins(getActivity());**

Comment: it is giving me same error of nullpointerException , I know it already that I have to pass the context , I did it and its giving me the nullpointerException

Comment: how ever the getAllPins method is in the Mapfragment , would MainActivity.this would work in it ?

Comment: Nop... When u call from fragment, it should be like this, GetAllPins(getActivity());

Comment: You should also make sure that the fragment has been attached to the activity before you try to access the activity from the fragment.

Comment: yeah it is attached as I can see my location on it the map is initialized and every thing is done

Comment: @AlexHart well how to check it that the fragment is attached or not ?

Comment: @StacyQueen It will have called onAttach, and getActivity will return non-null value

Comment: should I write  my own made function GetAllPins into a onAttach ?

Comment: Either there or in onActivityCreated